# Displaying server name last 4 digits only using javascript

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to display the server name of my server in commented region. 
I can display the server name however, we are not allowed to display the whole server name. 
i am using following code to display the server name that can be read in page source view..

```
<!--<%=Environment.MachineName%>-->
```

It displays the whole machinename, is there a way i can display just the last 4 digits of the server name....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used

```
         <!--<%=Environment.MachineName.Substring(Environment.MachineName.Length-4)%>--> It works the way I want
```

Answer (score 1):

as machinename is an ordinary string, this one should solve your problem

```
<%=Environment.MachineName.Length > 4 ?
 Environment.MachineName.Substring(Environment.MachineName.Length-4,4) :
 Environment.MachineName %>
```